# Concatenate Python Linked List

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I am attempting to concatenate a Python linked list without copying the data contained within the nodes of the list. I have a function that will concatenate the list using copies of the nodes passed in, but I can't seem to get the function that doesn't use copies to work.

These functions are for testing and timing purposes; I know that Python's built-in list is awesome!

Here is the class I have been working with and the concatenate function.

```
class Cell:
    def __init__( self, data, next = None ):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

def print_list(self):
    node = self
    while node != None:
        print node.data
        node = node.next
```

The concatenation function is not meant to be a member function of the Cell class.

```
def list_concat(A, B):
    while A.next != None:
        A = A.next
    A.next = B      
    return A
```

This function overwrites the first element of a list if the parameter A has more than one node. I understand why that is happening, but am not sure how to go about fixing it.

Here is the testing code I've been using for this function.

```
e = Cell(5)
test = Cell(3, Cell(4))
test2 = list_concat(test2, e)   
test2.print_list()
```

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

*edited to fix code formatting

Comment: Your concatenation function should work. Note that `list` is not a linked list. I would suggest that you look at lisp implementations, as they use cells of the same structure as you do.

Comment: I thought this implementation should work as well, however when I print the list (test2) it lists the elements as 4 -> 5 -> None, when it should list 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> None.

Comment: Note that in your code example, you are using test2 as a parameter before you are assigning to it.

Comment: Does this deserve the homework tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
def list_concat(A, B):
    current = A
    while current.next != None:
        current = current.next
    current.next = B
    return A
```

Assigning new values to a function's parameters is a bad programming practice, and the code in your question shows why: You used `A` for iterating over the original list, and by doing so, you lost the reference to its first element.

Comment: Another possibility is to just break the "find the end of the list" part into a separate function that returns the last node. Then it's `list_concat(A, B): find_end(A).next = B; return A`

Comment: Or, and I'm ashamed to have just thought of his, *don't return the list at all* like Python's built-in `list` class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on about if `extend` performs a copy or not, but in case it doesn't, just use

```
A.extend(B)
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you said you are doing this for testing purposes